# Passing a vector or a vector of vectors or a vector of ... (you get the idea) to a function

Tags: c++, vector

I'm writing an API for a Machine Learning, and I need to have an overloaded function that can either receive a **vector** as an argument, or a **vector of vectors** (for a batch job).

I'm a having a bit of a problem with calling the function though.

As an simpler example, the function might look like this:

```
void bar( const std::vector<float>& arg ) {
  std::cout << "BAR: Vector of float" << std::endl;
}
void bar( const std::vector<std::vector<float>>& arg ) {
  std::cout << "BAR: Vector of vectors of float" << std::endl;
}
```

So, I'd expect that I could call it like this:

```
 bar( { 1,2,3 } );
 bar( { { 1,2,3 } } );
```

But on the second one the IDE complains that, BOTH overloaded functions match the argument list, and so I have to call it like this for it to work.

```
bar( { { { 1,2,3 } } } );
```

Why is that? Wouldn't that be a vector of vectors of vectors (i.e. a "3D-vector")?

The same is when I'm passing a previously initialized vector:

```
std::vector<float> v = { 1,2,3,4,5 };

bar( v );
bar( { v } );
```

Both print out the `BAR: Vector of float` message. So I now have to go:

```
bar( { { { v } } } );
```

for it to work, and this now looks like a 4D-vector. Am I missing something?

Comment: "Am I missing something?" Yes, when you go beyond the simple, most common examples, `initializer_list` and list-inti are really weird.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Welcome to brace hell.  When you have

```
bar( { 1,2,3 } );
```

the `{ 1,2,3 }` is treated as a `std::initializer_list<float>` and the only viable function to call is `void bar( const std::vector<float>& arg )`

When you have

```
bar( { { 1,2,3 } } );
```

Now `{ { 1,2,3 } }` can be construed as the outer braces denoting a `std::vector<float>`, and the inner braces the `std::initializer_list<float>` for it, or could be the construction of a `std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<float>>` to be used to construct the 2d vector.  Either option is just as good, so you get an ambiguity.  As yo found, the solution is

```
bar( { { { 1,2,3 } } } );
```

So now the outer most set of braces denotes creating a `std::vector<std::vector<float>>` and the second outer most braces denote the start of a `std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<float>>` and the inmost braces being an element of that.

With

```
bar( v );
bar( { v } );
```

It is a little more complicated.  Obviously `bar( v );` will do what you want, but `bar( { v } );` actually works unlike `bar( { { 1,2,3 } } );` because of the rules in [[over.ics.list]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/over.ics.list).  Specifically, [paragraph 7](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/over.ics.list#7) says that `{ v }` is an exact match for creating a `std::vector<float>` via the copy constructor while creating a `std::vector<std::vector<float>>` is a user defined conversion.  This means that calling `void bar( const std::vector<float>& arg )` is a better match and that is what you see.  You need to use

```
bar( { { { v } } } );
```

so that the outer set of braces denotes the `std::vector<std::vector<float>>` and the middle set is the start of the `std::initializer_list<std::vector<float>>`, and the innermost set is the single `std::vector<float>` element of that list.

Answer (score 3):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60547850/4944425) by [NathanOliver](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4342498/nathanoliver) explains the reasons of the ambiguity.

If you are interested in distinguish all those cases, you should add other overloads:

```
#include <initializer_list>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void bar( std::vector<float> const& arg ) {
  std::cout << "BAR: Vector of float, size " << arg.size() << '\n';
}

void bar( std::vector<std::vector<float>> const& arg ) {
  std::cout << "BAR: Vector of vectors of float, size " << arg.size() << '\n';
}

void bar( std::initializer_list<float> lst ) {
  std::cout << "BAR: Initializer list of float, size " << lst.size() << '\n';
}

void bar( std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<float>> lst ) {
  std::cout << "BAR: Initializer list of initializer list of float, size "
            << lst.size() << '\n';
}

void bar( std::initializer_list<std::vector<float>> lst ) {
  std::cout << "BAR: Initializer list of vector of float, size "
            << lst.size() << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    bar( { 1,2,3 } );     // -> Initializer list of float
    bar( { { 1,2,3 } } ); // -> Initializer list of initializer list of float

    std::vector<float> v = { 1,2,3,4,5 };

    bar( v );     // -> Vector of float
    bar( { v } ); // -> Initializer list of vector of float
}
```

Live, [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/U59uHlYPxo7NymhN).

Comment: ok, that seems like a good idea, gonna try it tomorrow. I can have fewer different names for functions that do pretty much the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

It is very interesting case of `list initialization`.

```
bar({1, 2, 3})
bar({{1, 2, 3}})
```

It is copy list initialization case, here a temporary object is created by copy list initialization and const reference is bound to it.

To understand how `bar()` functions call work, it requires to understand how list initialization works and overload resolution rules of it. So let's go one by one,

`std::vector<double> vec = {0, 1};`
This is also list initialization (copy list initialization), `std::vector` have following constructor,

```
vector( std::initializer_list<T> init,
        const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

`std::initializer_list<T>` constructor have highest preference compare to other constructor in overload resolution and due to this overload resolution select it.

Another case,

```
std::vector<double> vec = {0, 1};
std::vector<double> other = {vec};
```

It is different case, now curly braces have **one element** only and it is exactly the type of `other` variable (which is `std::vector<double>`), as per the `list initialization` overload resolution rules, more details at [special rules for overload resolution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution#Implicit_conversion_sequence_in_list-initialization), following happens,
Overload resolution doesn't select `std::initializer_list<T>` **constructor** rather it selects **copy constructor**, it is **Exact Match rank** case, read about it in link provided above. Now this case will help to understand what is happening behind the screen.

Let look at following code,

```
std::vector<double> other = {{0, 1}};
```

As per the previous discussion, compiler should fist create a temporary `std::vector<double>` and then **move initialize** variable `other` but fortunately compiler doesn't do it, rather it does following,
So rather creating a temporary `std::vector<double>` and then **move intitialize** variable `other` it optimise-out temporary object and directly initialize `other` variable by calling `std::initializer_list` **constructor** with `{0, 1}` as constructor argument.

Finally the last case,

```
std::vector<std::vector<double>> nestedVec = {{0, 1}};
```

Compiler will first create a temporary `std::vector<double>` and it means above express logically become `std::vector<std::vector<double>> nestedVec = {std::vector<double>{0, 1}};` and then overload resolution will select `std::initializer_list` constructor.
So the learning is , expression `{{1, 2, 3}}` is capable to intialize `std::vector<double>` as well as `std::vector<std::vector<double>>` and creating ambiguity in `bar()` function call, it also means `std::initializer_list` with single element should be used carefully.

Now to resolve ambiguity, following can be done,
change function call,

```
bar({1, 2, 3});
bar({{1, 2, 3}, {}}); //put an empty element.
```

or use more pair of curly braces as described in question

```
bar({{{1, 2, 3}}});
```

or first crate a variable and pass this variable as function argument rather then passing `std::initializer_list` as function argument.

following code will demo what i have explained,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using std::cout;

template <class T>
class Container{
public:
    Container(){
        cout<< "Default contructor.\n"<< __PRETTY_FUNCTION__<< '\n';
    }

    Container(const Container& ){
        cout<< "Copy contructor.\n"<< __PRETTY_FUNCTION__<< '\n';
    }

    Container(Container&& ){
        cout<< "Move contructor.\n"<< __PRETTY_FUNCTION__<< '\n';
    }

    Container(const std::initializer_list<T>& ){
        cout<< "std::initializer_list contructor.\n"<< __PRETTY_FUNCTION__<< '\n';
    }
};

int main(int , char *[]){
    std::cout<<"1 --- ";
    Container<double> dObj; //1
    cout<< '\n';

    std::cout<<"2 --- ";
    [[maybe_unused]] Container<double> cObj = {dObj}; //2
    cout<< '\n';

    std::cout<<"3 --- ";
    [[maybe_unused]] Container<double> lObj = {{0, 1}}; //3
    cout<< '\n';

    std::cout<<"4 --- ";
    [[maybe_unused]] Container<Container<double>> nObj = {{0, 1}}; //4
    cout<< '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
1 --- Default contructor.
Container<T>::Container() [with T = double]

2 --- Copy contructor.
Container<T>::Container(const Container<T>&) [with T = double]

3 --- std::initializer_list contructor.
Container<T>::Container(const std::initializer_list<_Tp>&) [with T = double]

4 --- std::initializer_list contructor.
Container<T>::Container(const std::initializer_list<_Tp>&) [with T = double]
std::initializer_list contructor.
Container<T>::Container(const std::initializer_list<_Tp>&) [with T = Container<double>]
```